# Get current and average speed - Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-plugins

The following code would allow for tracking and giving the speed of a user.

I'd like to have this info, and even average speed,
but I receive this error:

> "166:37 Uncaught TypeError: previousLatLng.distanceTo is not a function"

This is strange because the function is called with let. I'm using Leaflet plugin [leaflet-control-geocoder](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder) and [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/) library.

This was previously discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72071582/how-can-i-compute-current-speed-average-speed-and-total-distance-with-leafletjs/72073783?noredirect=1#comment129498674_72073783
where "*Leaflet provides a useful latlngA.distanceTo(latlngB) method to convert a pair of GPS coordinates into actual distance*"

I made a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vincedchart/01f8rjzb/1/

```
      const exportButton = document.getElementById("export");
      let intv;

      const status = document.getElementById("status");

      var map = L.map("map", {
        center: [9.082, 8.6753],
        zoom: 8,
      });
      var osm = L.tileLayer(
        "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
        {
          attribution:
                                '&copy; <a href="https://skatespot.com">SkateSpot, Inc.</a>',
        }
      ).addTo(map);
      L.Control.geocoder().addTo(map);
      if (!navigator.geolocation) {
        console.log("Your browser doesn't support geolocation feature!");
      }

      const trackingPath = [];
      const polyline = L.polyline([], {
        color: "red",
        weight: 3,
        className: "path",
      }).addTo(map);

      function start() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition);
        intv = setInterval(() => {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition);
        }, 1000);
      }

   
   let totalElapsedTime = 0;
let totalDistance = 0;
let previousTime;
let previousLatLng;

function getPosition(position) {
  const time = new Date();
  const latLng = L.latLng(
    position.latitude,
    position.longitude
  );

  // Skip first point (no computation is possible)
  if (previousTime && previousLatLng) {
    const elapsedTime = (time.getTime() - previousTime.getTime()) / 1000; // In seconds
    const distance = previousLatLng.distanceTo(latLng);

    const currentSpeed = distance / elapsedTime; // In meters / second

    totalElapsedTime += elapsedTime;
    totalDistance += distance;

    const averageSpeed = totalDistance / totalElapsedTime; // In meters / second
  }

  // Record time and position for next computation
  previousTime = time;
  previousLatLng = position;

  // Graphic stuff...
}

  

      function startTracking(e) {
        status.innerText = "Started tracking...";
        e.preventDefault();
        start();
      }

      function stopTracking(e) {
        status.innerText = "Stopped tracking.";
        e.preventDefault();
        clearInterval(intv);
      }

      document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", startTracking);
      document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", stopTracking);
      document.getElementById("marker").addEventListener("click", addMarker);
    </script>
```

Comment: @TomazicM hello, ok it's done (added the js and css links, I don't see anything else)

Comment: What is `.distanceTo` supposed to be? Where does it come from? `navigatotor.geolocation` position has only `coords` and `timestamp` properties, no methods.

Comment: @TomazicM I edited post with the source and an explanation about .distanceTo that's also in the Leaflet.js explanation page https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng-distanceto

Comment: But `.distanceTo` is valid only for `L.latLng` coordinates. `position` coordinate is created by browser, not by Leaflet, so it does not have that method.

Comment: `previousLatLng` is not an instance of `L.LatLng`. Pay attention to `previousLatLng = position;`.

Comment: @TomazicM so... could I pass the info to Leaflet or do something like this ?

Comment: All you have to do is to replace statement `previousLatLng = position;` with `previousLatLng = latLng;`

Comment: @TomazicM thank you, in fact I needed to do that and also replace   const latLng = L.latLng(
    position.latitude,
    position.longitude
  ); by   const latLng = L.latLng(
    latitude,
    longitude
  );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
previousLatLng = position;
```

with

```
previousLatLng = latLng
```

and

```
const latLng = L.latLng( position.latitude, position.longitude );
```

by

```
const latLng = L.latLng( latitude, longitude );
```

and all this, inside the function getPosition(position) :
convert speed to kph without decimals :

```
const currentSpeedkmh = currentSpeed * 3.6;
      const currentSpeedready = Math.trunc ( currentSpeedkmh );
```

and

```
  const averageSpeedkmh = averageSpeed * 3.6;
  const averageSpeedready = Math.trunc( averageSpeedkmh );
```

get the status updated:

```
                const vit = [currentSpeedready, averageSpeedready];
          status.innerText = `Current and average speed ${vit.join(", ")}`;
```